# How do I relocate the pop up notifications in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

Currently, they pop up in the bottom right corner, but that is frequently in the way. I'd like to move them elsewhere. Like, say, the top corner.

Google searches only showed me a registry edit that worked 2 years ago and no longer does anything.

Comment: By registry edit, do you mean that of `DisplayToastAtBottom` ?

Comment: yes              
that's the one

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know of another method.